# Error while downloading Excel from django with nginx

Tags: python, django, excel, nginx, gunicorn

The django server served using nginx creates an excel file using pandas and BytesIO and then returns an HttpRespose as follows:

```py
data = export_data.export_data()
response = HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Download.xlsx"'
return response
```

The template has an anchor that references to this view.
This works fine with only django ( local testing )
but in production ( with nginx ) it gives me the following error :

```
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
```

NGINX CONFIG :

```
upstream my-server {
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 11.11.1.3;

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /my-server/logs/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /my-server/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /my-sever/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /my-server/media/;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://my-server;
    }
}
```

Please help me in resolving this problem.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What happens if you specify `content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8'`?

Comment: @physicalattraction nothing changes on this side, still the same error